# How to set onTouchListener on BitMap

Tags: android, bitmap, touch-event, ontouchlistener

How do I set an onTouchListener for a Bitmap. e.g

```
   pongball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pongball);
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the bitmap object into a View, for example into an `ImageView`:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(pongball);
```

then set the touch listener to the ImageView:

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: whenever I do this my app crashes